# Android Studio Speeding up Emulator?

Tags: android, mobile, emulation

Any way I could speed up the Android Studio Emulator even on an older laptop? I don't have a physical android device to plug in and rely on the emulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got two tips:
Disable the Boot Animation 
Click Debug Configurations > Your Debug Configuration > Target and un-select that option

and the biggest thing that will help is literally never closing the emulator. If it's open and you're not using it, just let it be. Closing it and opening it again later takes forever

Answer (score 2):

For Android Emulator, I always use [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/). You should use it to speed up emulation on Android.

I'm working with Android Studio and it's working fine !

Comment: I install that and then select it when launching my application from Android Studios?

Comment: You should start Genymotion and your virtual device before selecting it in Android Studio. But you'll see that it's quite faster than the official emulator.